# Inversion on large types with impredicative-set enabled

Tags: coq

In my setting I am using Coq with the `-impredicative-set` flag and have the following data type with an existential type in its constructor.

```coq
Set Implicit Arguments.

Inductive ext : Set :=
| ext_ : forall (X: Set), X -> ext.
```

Then I define an equality for my data type.

```coq
Variable eqXY: forall X, X -> X -> Prop.

Inductive Eq_ext : ext  -> ext -> Prop :=
| eq_ext : forall (X : Set)
             (x y: X),
    eqXY x y ->
    Eq_ext (ext_ x) (ext_ y).
```

I like my equality to be a relation, thus, reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity would be preferable properties. The first two are no problem, but for transitivity I end up with a problem concerning `inversion`.

```coq
Variable eqXY_trans: forall X (x y z:X), eqXY x y -> eqXY y z -> eqXY x z.

Lemma Eq_trans :
  forall (x y z: ext),
    Eq_ext x y -> Eq_ext y z -> Eq_ext x z.
Proof.
  intros.
  inversion H; subst.
  (* here is a snippet of the current hypothesis:

     X : Set
     x0, y0 : X
     H0 : Eq_ext (ext_ y0) z
     H1 : eqXY x0 y0

   *)
  inversion H0; subst.
  (*
     X : Set
     x0, y0 : X
     X0 : Set
     y : X0
     H0 : Eq_ext (ext_ y0) (ext_ y)
     H : Eq_ext (ext_ x0) (ext_ y0)
     H1 : eqXY x0 y0
     x : X0
     H3 : ext_ x = ext_ y0
     H2 : eqXY x y
  *)
  Fail apply eq_ext.
  admit.
Admitted.
```

In my naive expectation, I wanted `z` to unify with `ext_ y` where `y` has type `X`, instead of a fresh type `X1`. Because now, for me, it looks like `H2` is a wrong hypothesis and should lead to a contradiction (and, thus, shouldn't come up in the first place or should be discarded when using `inversion` once again).
In my original expectation I could just use `eq_ext` because the types of `x0` and `y` are the same and the connection between `y` and `y0` would yield to a hypothesis `H3: eqXY y y0`.

As this is not the first time that I stumbled upon a problem with this kind of data type, I do know that I cannot project the first component of my `ext_`-constructor. So my first guess is that this all plays together with the behaviour of inversion in my example.

However, I would like to know for sure that there is some connection or, alternatively, that there is a different explanation for this behaviour. Because of my late experiences with this data type, I guess that there is no workaround to get my transitivity lemma, but if this a false assumption, I really appreciate some insights!

Edit: As metioned in the comments I need define the data type in `Set` and cannot define it in `Type` because of other restrictions.

Comment: I think that the exact problem you're having might be related to impredicativity, but can you get the proof to go through if you put `ext` in `Type` instead of `Set`? My guess is that it shouldn't be possible...

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add that I need to be in `Set` because of other restrictions; I will add that to the original post.

Comment: That is OK, but I think the problem is more fundamental then having impredicative set turned on. I don't think this proof would work if you use `Type`, even if it makes that particular problematic line in your proof work.

Comment: I read over the "not" part in "shouldn't". I will check out your hunch!

Comment: To prove an analogous thing using `Type` I had to make `X` a parameter of `Eq_ext ` and throw in the `eq_dep_eq` axiom. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anton-trunov/7be25a294ad5151887466e528bf6609d) for details. HTH.

Comment: Thank you very much; I didn't know how to handle these `existT`-values and somehow got lost searching for the right lemma. Do you think there is also some way to do this in `Set` with `--impredicaive-set` enabled?

Comment: I think it's impossible (but I'd love to see an example proving me wrong). `Check (fun (X : Set) (x y : X) (H : ext_ x = ext_ y) => (f_equal (fun e : ext => match e with | @ext_ X x => existT (fun Y : Set => Y) X x end) H)).` generates the following error message: `Incorrect elimination of "e" in the inductive type "ext":
the return type has sort "Type" while it should be "Prop" or "Set".
Elimination of an inductive object of sort Set
is not allowed on a predicate in sort Type
because strong elimination on non-small inductive types leads to paradoxes.`

Comment: If we use `exist` instead `existT`, then we understandably will get a universe inconsistency error. By the way, beware of the bad interactions of new axioms with the impredicative `Set` [What standard axioms are inconsistent with Coq?](https://coq.inria.fr/faq#htoc38)